# Issue with installing Alamofire and using it in project

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I have an issue with Alamofire which I am trying to install on my project. I followed the instructions on the Alamofire github (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to install it with cocoapods and I followed the instructions. I ran pod install on my pod file which had the content

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.3’
use_frameworks!

target 'voteDJ' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

However, my project has a build time error on my Alamofire import telling me that there is no such module named Alamofire, even though there is an Alamofire.framework file in my frameworks as well as it being in my linked frameworks and libraries. When I look inside the Alamofire framework it does not seem to contain any modules or headers for some reason. Please comment if I need more information, I am not sure exactly what else to provide, but I cannot figure out why these instructions are not working.

Comment: Did u added post install hook? Looks like -   post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end

Comment: make sure you are using workspace file not xcodeproject file

Comment: Is 'voteDJ' your target name and did you try building the project (not run but build)

Comment: What version of Cocoapods are you using? When I had this issue, my version of Cocoapods was below the version required to install Alamofire (You need the latest Cocoapods to install the latest version of Alamofire).